# How to create a state machine diagram using C# in enterprise architect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-architect

I can ask the user to create all the elements that will be present in the diagram, but i am not able to visualize the best way to allow user to create the connectors which will be linking all those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Create a Diagram

```
EA.Diagram newDiag = package.Diagrams.Addnew("DiagramName","Statechart");
newDiag.update();
```

Create Connectors for elements using

```
EA.connector con = element.connectors.Addnew("ConnectorName","ConnectorType");
con.supplierid="targetelementid";
con.clientid = "sourceelementid";
con.update();
```

And using layout diagram call layout the connectors to autoroute.

> `Repository.App.Project.LayoutDiagramEx`

**LayoutDiagramEx call is the best way to visualise the created connectors programatically.**

Comment: You should preferably create a state machine diagram only under a State Machine element, not in the package directly.